# Import into Hive using Sqoop Java.io error

Tags: java, hadoop, sqoop

I am using Sqoop to try import a sql server table into Hive. The connection string is working correctly but the import is failing. Below is the output. I am getting the same error if I try import into HDFS as well. Does anyone know what the issue might be?

```
[cloudera@ushydgnadipalvx sqoop]$ sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://[server];username=[username];password=[password];database=[dbname]" --table [tablename] --hive-import
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
15/07/10 15:31:41 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.3-cdh4.7.0
15/07/10 15:31:41 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: Using Hive-specific delimiters for output. You can override
15/07/10 15:31:41 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: delimiters with --fields-terminated-by, etc.
15/07/10 15:31:41 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
15/07/10 15:31:41 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
15/07/10 15:31:43 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM [SocialDatas] AS t WHERE 1=0
15/07/10 15:31:45 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce
/tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/0159bb09ed314f098b249cb4c7c97130/SocialDatas.java:206: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method readString(java.io.DataInput)
location: class java.lang.String
    this.Language = Text.readString(__dataIn);
                        ^
/tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/0159bb09ed314f098b249cb4c7c97130/SocialDatas.java:211: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method readString(java.io.DataInput)
location: class java.lang.String
    this.Platform = Text.readString(__dataIn);
                        ^
/tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/0159bb09ed314f098b249cb4c7c97130/SocialDatas.java:216: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method readString(java.io.DataInput)
location: class java.lang.String
    this.Text = Text.readString(__dataIn);
                    ^
/tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/0159bb09ed314f098b249cb4c7c97130/SocialDatas.java:257: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method writeString(java.io.DataOutput,java.lang.String)
location: class java.lang.String
    Text.writeString(__dataOut, Language);
        ^
/tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/0159bb09ed314f098b249cb4c7c97130/SocialDatas.java:263: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method writeString(java.io.DataOutput,java.lang.String)
location: class java.lang.String
    Text.writeString(__dataOut, Platform);
        ^
/tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/0159bb09ed314f098b249cb4c7c97130/SocialDatas.java:269: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method writeString(java.io.DataOutput,java.lang.String)
location: class java.lang.String
    Text.writeString(__dataOut, Text);
        ^
Note: /tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/0159bb09ed314f098b249cb4c7c97130/SocialDatas.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
6 errors
15/07/10 15:31:47 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Error returned by javac
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.CompilationManager.compile(CompilationManager.java:217)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:97)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:396)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:506)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:222)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:231)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:240)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that I had a column name called "Text" and that was causing the error. I fixed it by renaming my column.

Answer (score 0):

Errors in output shown above are due to hadoop jars not being in CLASSPATH. Try to import after setting proper CLASSPATH. Below is example for `tcsh` shell.

```
setenv CLASSPATH $HADOOP_HOME/lib/*:$CLASSPATH
```

Comment: Hi @Shubhangi, thanks for the response, but I have tried to import a different table from my database and it worked correctly, so maybe an issue with the table i'm trying to import